# Ruby Cucumber trimming leading zero from string Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to enter a number into a field that starts with leading zeros.  When this number gets entered, the leading zeros are removed.

Expected: `000632` Actual: `632`

These are the last 6 digits of a longer number so I need the zero(s) there.

The paramenter that this number is used in has been converted to a string but it's still removing the zeros.

I do have a Transform block in my env file to automatically convert digits to integer:

```
Transform /^\d+$/ do |number|
  number.to_i
end
```

Although the regex used for my string is `([^"]*/)`

It looks like the Transform block is interfering. Is there a way around this? I'm no Regex master :-)

Thanks

Comment: That's why I don't use transforms. I get too many unintended consequences.

Comment: Something that I'm starting to realise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform blocks are checked for match against every match extracted in your test steps.  Because of this the string "000632" matches to the transform you posted and you get the integer extracted instead of the wanted string.  If you want to prevent strings of digits beginning with 0 from matching you need to change your transform regex to something like

```
Transform /^[1-9]\d*$/ do |number|
  number.to_i
end
```

which will then only match strings of digits beginning with 1-9

Comment: Thanks once again, Tom. That's helped.